# Adding objects in constructor in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, constructor

I'm trying to add every task which has been created in constructor

```
static private int Id = 0;
private int id = 0;
private Date StartDate;
private Date EndDate;
private static ArrayList<Task> Tasks;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

public Task(java.util.Date StartDate, java.util.Date EndDate) {
    try{
        this.setStartDate(StartDate);
        this.setEndDate(EndDate);
        setId(Id++);

        System.out.println(this.id + this.EndDate.toString() + this.StartDate.toString());
        Tasks.add(this);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

It throws NullPointException.

I couldn't find out a way to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: debug it. or post the stacktrace

Comment: You haven't initialized `Tasks`.

Comment: why do you think `Tasks.add(this);` would work when `Tasks` has not been initialised?

Comment: private static ArrayList<Task> Tasks = new ArrayList<Task>(); solved the problem. Thank you so much all.